# SDL keyboard inputs not triggering

Tags: c++, eclipse, input, sdl

I am trying to make a simple text game, but I have come across an odd problem. I have a class set up to take inputs from the user's keyboard using SDL_KEYDOWN. When ever the function `check_event()` is called it runs a loop that polls keyboard input and returns a string for the button. The odd thing is that pressing down on the keys have no effect. The code stops for my while loop, but it seems like my function has no effect at all.

Here is my main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
#include "input.h"


using namespace std;

Input input;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO) != 0) {
            SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
            return 1;
        }

     cout << "Welcome to Hero V1.0!" << endl; //intro stuff
     cout << "Written By: Jojo" << endl;
     cout << endl;

     cout << "1) New Game" << endl;
     cout << "2) Continue Game" << endl;


     while (true) {
         string event = input.check_event();
         if(event == "1"){
             cout << "Test" << flush;
         }
     }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my input class .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Input.h"
using namespace std;
string Input::check_event() {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_1:
                    return "1";
                }
            }
        }
        return "null";
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to have created a window. SDL don't have buitin full-system input grab functionality (which, for many reasons, might be problemmatic or not-very-possible to implement). For text game keypresses you need to read from stdin (read, getch, ...).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple red flags.

Firstly, `std::cout` does not work with [sdl](/questions/tagged/sdl). The library uses windows, not consoles/terminals. If you want to render text, read an appropriate tutorial.

Secondly, you can't check events if you haven't initialised an event handler. You should have added `SDL_Event event;` before the [while](/questions/tagged/while) loop.

Thirdly, using a [class](/questions/tagged/class) to handle input is unnecessary, this is more suitable:

```
bool quit = false;
SDL_Event event;

while (!quit)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
        }

         // Add if blocks, switch statements, and what have you
    }
}
```